# Problems with Syntax?

Tags: sql, join, count

I use a system that doesn't allow me access to the SQL database directly and I have to use their in built reporting tool which is just awful. I'm running the below code and its telling me there is a syntax error near ) but I can't see myself how this is incorrect, any ideas?

```
SELECT ST.Staff_ID,
COUNT (CASE WHEN Referral_Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate ) AS 'Referrals',
COUNT (CASE WHEN Att_Start_Dttm BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate ) AS 'Appointments'

FROM tbldiaryappointment DA
left outer join tblDiaryAppointmentClinicianInvitee CI on DA.Diary_Appointment_ID = CI.Diary_Appointment_ID
left outer join tblstaff ST on CI.Clinician_Invitee_Staff_ID = ST.STaff_ID
left outer join tbllocation LOC on LOC.Location_ID = DA.Scheduled_Location_ID
left outer join tblpatient PAT on PAT.Patient_ID = DA.Patient_ID
left outer join tblAttendanceTypeValues ATV on ATV.Attendance_Type_ID = DA.Attendance_Type_ID
left outer join tblDiaryAppointmentScheduledEvent SE on SE.Diary_Appointment_ID = DA.Diary_Appointment_ID
left outer join tblEventValues EVE on EVE.Event_ID = SE.Event_ID
left outer join tblProfessionalGroupValues PGV on ST.Professional_Group_ID = PGV.Professional_Group_ID
left outer join tblStaffJobRoleCodeValues JOB on JOB.Staff_Job_Role_Code_ID = ST.Job_Role_Code_ID
left outer join tblReferral REF on REF.Patient_ID = DA.Patient_ID
```

Comment: Your `CASE WHEN` is not complete, it should contain a `THEN ... END`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax for Searched CASE expression is:

```
CASE
     WHEN Boolean_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END
```

You're missing the part after `Boolean_expression`.

Also, your statement is missing `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT ST.Staff_ID,
COUNT (CASE WHEN Referral_Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate THEN 1 END) AS 'Referrals',
COUNT (CASE WHEN Att_Start_Dttm BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate THEN 1 END ) AS 'Appointments'

FROM tbldiaryappointment DA
left outer join tblDiaryAppointmentClinicianInvitee CI on DA.Diary_Appointment_ID = CI.Diary_Appointment_ID
left outer join tblstaff ST on CI.Clinician_Invitee_Staff_ID = ST.STaff_ID
left outer join tbllocation LOC on LOC.Location_ID = DA.Scheduled_Location_ID
left outer join tblpatient PAT on PAT.Patient_ID = DA.Patient_ID
left outer join tblAttendanceTypeValues ATV on ATV.Attendance_Type_ID = DA.Attendance_Type_ID
left outer join tblDiaryAppointmentScheduledEvent SE on SE.Diary_Appointment_ID = DA.Diary_Appointment_ID
left outer join tblEventValues EVE on EVE.Event_ID = SE.Event_ID
left outer join tblProfessionalGroupValues PGV on ST.Professional_Group_ID = PGV.Professional_Group_ID
left outer join tblStaffJobRoleCodeValues JOB on JOB.Staff_Job_Role_Code_ID = ST.Job_Role_Code_ID
left outer join tblReferral REF on REF.Patient_ID = DA.Patient_ID
GROUP BY ST.Staff_ID
```

Comment: My answers don't appear untested. That may be the reason I'm not posting right away what comes to my mind, and thus am not first in "the race".

Comment: I stand corrected.  Thanks for the quality check.  And yes, it's too bad that there is a big race, because so many people waste their answers trying to post first.